# Drag a div with text and drop on another to replace text

Tags: jquery, html, replace, drag-and-drop

I have spent quite a bit of time searching through the stacks trying to find an answer to this question but nothing is really pointing me in the right direction. What I'm trying to accomplish is dragging div box A and dropping it on div box B and the content in B is replaced with the content from A. I have created a fiddle with a modified, stripped down sample from the jQuery UI site, and I know that the .appendTo is what I need to change, but I cannot figure out what to change it to in order to replace the existing text.

http://jsfiddle.net/66CrN/

```
$(function() {  
$( "#officer div" ).draggable({      
appendTo: "body",      
helper: "clone"    
});    

$( "#schedule" ).droppable({      
activeClass: "ui-state-default",      
hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",      
accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",      
drop: function( event, ui ) {        
$( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();        
$( "<span></span>" ).text( ui.draggable.text()).appendTo( this );     
   }    
 });  
});
```

Any help as always is appreciated.

Thanks for looking at my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
$(this).empty();
```

Instead of

```
$( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
```

That will clear the schedule everytime a new element is appended

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/66CrN/1/)

Another option would be

```
$(this).html($("<span></span>").text(ui.draggable.text()));
```

Comment: Awesome! I can't believe it was that easy, I've tried all kinds of combinations of things on the appendTo row that I didnt think about this one. It will let me mark correct in 10 minutes apparently and I will do so then. My follow up question would be, in order to submit this to a MySQL database, I would have to also make the drop change the HTML code to reflect the new name correct?

Comment: @PHaeLiX are you updating on drop or when you click on a button?

Comment: It was going to be when I click a button. I am writing a scheduling app and dont really want the changes committed until everything is in order. Unless you see a reason that updating on drop would be better, but it just seems like a lot of extra calls to the server when I can just make one.

Comment: @PHaeLiX are you using ajax to submit? and in your case updating on drop would not make much sense

Comment: Originally I was going to use PHP to submit, but I've been looking more into using Ajax to do it so I can try to validate that everything is filled in prior to sending it to PHP for second validation. If i dont update the HTML on drop, when I go to submit how will anything know what it currently is?

Comment: @PHaeLiX my idea would be to make a form, and append the selected text as a hidden input. then you can easily submit that form via ajax or normal submit. http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/66CrN/2/

Comment: Again man thank you so much for all your help. You truely are a gentleman and a scholar!